# Join query returns no records for CURDATE

Tags: mysql

While running the below JOIN query, I am not able to get the data. There is actually 1 record available with `updatedAt` date = 2020-06-30 ( please see screen shot )

I would like to create a JOIN query to display data for `createdAt or updatedAt` date = CURDATE()

Below query is returning no records, please see the screenshot:

[image]

```
SELECT user.id, user.photo, user.position, availability.dailystatus 
FROM user  
join availability  
ON user.id = availability.id where (SELECT DATE((availability.createdAt) or (availability.updatedAt))) = CURDATE();
```

[image]

Comment: What is user_id in availability table are you sure that cortect match condition ?

Comment: Please ignore the `user_id` column for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OR` operator returns a boolean, either `0` or `1`, not a `datetime`. So it makes little sense to use that as the argument to `DATE()`.

If you want to test whether either date is equal to `CURDATE()`, you need to do separate comparisons and combine them with `OR`.

Also, you shouldn't do this in a subquery, you should be testing the row being selected.

```
SELECT user.id, user.photo, user.position, availability.dailystatus 
FROM user  
join availability  
ON user.id = availability.id
WHERE DATE(availability.createdAt) = CURDATE()
OR DATE(availability.updatedAt) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: @Akina Thanks, I didn't notice the `DATE()` call.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, the udpated answer is working fine, why the sub query was not work ing earlier.

Comment: @soccerway be advised that functions cannot use indexes

Answer (score 0):

shouldnt you be joining tables on `user.id = availability.user_id ?` It seems like you are joining it on wrong column